# Show how many times a specific number is found in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, search, integer, console-application

The first part of my code is where the input numbers are put into an array, this part works fine. In the second part you need to read in a searchterm and search for the searchterm in the array. After searching for it I need to show how many times the searchterm is found in the array. The second part is what i have tried but it doesn't work.

```
int[] number = new int[20];
int i = 0;
int notnull = 1;
while ( ( i < 20 ) && ( notnull != 0 ) )
{
  Console.Write("Give a number <0 = stop> : ");
  number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  notnull = number[i];
  i++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Give searchterm (number): ");
int searchterm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int count = 1;
if ( searchterm == number[i] )
  count++;

Console.WriteLine("The number {0} shows up {1} times", searchterm, count);
```

Comment: `if (searchterm == number[i])` - you might want to do that kind of check for each item in the array. Also it seems likely that you're getting an exception here (since `number[20]` isn't indexable in a 20-item array), so you should include those details in your question. Oh, and, don't call your variable `notnull` - `0` is different to `null`, and it isn't possible for `int` to be null because it's a value type.

Comment: "Does not work" is really a bad problem description. Please, if you get a compiler-error, share its message. If you get an exception, share its message and stacktrace. If you get unexpected results, share expected vs actual results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily count items in an Array or an IEnumerable<T> in general, that have to fulfill a certain condition, with LINQ's [Count()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Console.WriteLine("Give searchterm (number): ");
int searchterm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int count = number.Count(i => i == searchterm);
Console.WriteLine("The number {0} shows up {1} times", searchterm, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static void Test()
{
  int capacity = 20;
  List<int> numbers = new List<int>(capacity);

  Console.WriteLine($"Enter up to {capacity} numbers (0 or not an integer to stop): ");
  int value = 0;
  do
  {
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value);
    if ( value != 0 )
      numbers.Add(value);
  }
  while ( numbers.Count < capacity && value != 0 );

  if ( numbers.Count > 0 )
  {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to search occurences: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value);
    if ( value > 0 )
    {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("The number {0} shows up {1} times",
                        value, 
                        numbers.Count(n => n == value));
    }
  }
}
```

Sample:

```
Enter up to a number (0 or not an integer to stop):
1
2
3
1
5
6
7
3
2
0

Enter un number to search occurences:
3

The number 3 shows up 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get rid of *magic numbers* - `20` in your case; let's change collecrtion's type: array doesn't have `Add` which `List<T>` provides:

```
   List<int> number = new List<int>();
```

Then let's be cafeful with user input: what if user put `bla-bla-bla`? In order to *avoid crash* we can use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

```
   while (true) {
     // 0 is not a good choice; let it be Q (Quit) instead
     Console.WriteLine("Give a number or Q to stop : ");

     // Trim: let's be nice and tolerate trailing/leading spaces 
     string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); 

     // Let's accept Q, q, quit, etc.
     if (input.StartsWith("Q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       break;           

     if (int.TryParse(input, out int value)) 
       number.Add(value);  
     else
       Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid input");
   }
```

Now we have `number` to work with. Let's obtain `searchterm` with the technique (TryParse)

```
   int searchterm = -1; // initialization, let compiler be happy

   while (true) {    
     Console.WriteLine("Give searchterm (number): ");

     if (int.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out searchterm))
       break;

     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid input");         
   }
```

Finally, let's compute `count`; usually we put *Linq* for this:

```
   int count = number.Count(searchterm);
```

However, if you want good old loops

```
   int count = 0;

   foreach (var item in number)
     if (item == searchterm) 
       count += 1;
```

Final suggestion is to use *string interpolation* as more readable then *formatting*:

```
   Console.WriteLine($"The number {searchterm} shows up {count} times");
```